# R - merge data frame columns with missing data in both columns

Tags: r, merge, missing-data

I have multiple data frames with repeat measures that i'd like to merge into a single data frame based on ID.

Some of these data are the same measure repeated at 5 timepoints, i.e. weight_1, weight_2, weight_3....

However, some don't change, i.e. Participant ID, Sex, date of birth.

I want to be able to keep all the repeat measure, but only one column for ID, sex, dob. The problem is that some participants have missing data from certain time points because they missed a session for example, and when i merge on the same variable it deletes the previous data and replaces it with NA if it was empty from that time point.

```
t1 
 PID  sex      DoB        Weight1
# P1    M     01/01/20       60
# P2    
# P3    F     01/01/20       90
# P4    M     01/01/20       80
# P5    F     01/01/20       80

t2 
 PID  sex      DoB        Weight2
# P1    M     01/01/20       61
# P2    M     01/01/20       65
# P3   
# P4    M     01/01/20       78
# P5    F     01/01/20       82

t3 
 PID  sex      DoB        Weight3
# P1    M     01/01/20       65
# P2    M     01/01/20       68
# P3    F     01/01/20       93
# P4    
# P5    F     01/01/20       83


#What i want
 PID  sex      DoB        Weight1   weight2  weight3
# P1    M     01/01/20       60        62       65
# P2    M     01/01/20                 65       68
# P3    F     01/01/20       90                 93
# P4    M     01/01/20       80        78       
# P5    F     01/01/20       80        82       83
```

I'm currently having to merge each data frame one by one, creating duplicate columns for sex and then create a new sex column each time, as below. surely there is an easier way?

```
combined_T <- merge(T1,T2, by=c("PID"),  all=T)

combined_T <- combined_T  %>% 
  add_column(Sex = "NA", .after = "PID") 

combined_T <- combined_T %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Sex = max(Sex.x, Sex.y, na.rm = T))

#drop two old sex columns
combined_T <-  subset(combined_T , select = -c(Sex.x,Sex.y))
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach works with your example data; does it work with your actual data?

```r
library(tidyverse)

t1 <- read.table(text = " PID  sex      DoB        Weight1
P1    M     01/01/20       60
P2
P3    F     01/01/20       90
P4    M     01/01/20       80
P5    F     01/01/20       80",
header = TRUE, fill = NA)

t2 <- read.table(text = " PID  sex      DoB        Weight2
P1    M     01/01/20       61
P2    M     01/01/20       65
P3
P4    M     01/01/20       78
P5    F     01/01/20       82",
header = TRUE, fill = NA)

t3 <- read.table(text = " PID  sex      DoB        Weight3
P1    M     01/01/20       65
P2    M     01/01/20       68
P3    F     01/01/20       93
P4
P5    F     01/01/20       83",
header = TRUE, fill = NA)

combined_T <- list(t1, t2, t3) %>%
  reduce(full_join, by = c("PID", "sex", "DoB")) %>%
  filter(sex == "M" | sex == "F") %>%
  arrange(PID) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~replace_na(., "")))

combined_T
#>   PID sex      DoB Weight1 Weight2 Weight3
#> 1  P1   M 01/01/20      60      61      65
#> 2  P2   M 01/01/20              65      68
#> 3  P3   F 01/01/20      90              93
#> 4  P4   M 01/01/20      80      78        
#> 5  P5   F 01/01/20      80      82      83
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

If you have lots of dataframes you could potentially use `ls()` to find the dataframes you want to merge, e.g.

```
combined_T <- mget(ls(pattern = "^t[[:digit:]]+")) %>%
  reduce(full_join, by = c("PID", "sex", "DoB")) %>%
  filter(sex == "M" | sex == "F") %>%
  arrange(PID) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~replace_na(., "")))
combined_T
#>   PID sex      DoB Weight1 Weight2 Weight3
#> 1  P1   M 01/01/20      60      61      65
#> 2  P2   M 01/01/20              65      68
#> 3  P3   F 01/01/20      90              93
#> 4  P4   M 01/01/20      80      78        
#> 5  P5   F 01/01/20      80      82      83
```

Comment: Awesome, that save me so much time! Unfortunately I'm getting the following error messageNote: Allactivities_T1 being one of my columns. any advice?

Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = across(everything(), ~replace_na(., ""))`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Problem while computing column `Allactivities_T1`.
Caused by error in `stop_vctrs()`:
! Can't convert `replace` <character> to match type of `data` <integer>.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.